# Routing gives error 404 in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the route component of symfony2 in my web app.
In my index.php I handle the routing:

```
// Handle routing
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader(new FileLocator(array(__DIR__ . '/../app/config')));
$collection = $loader->load('routing.yml');

$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($collection, $context);
$resolver = new ControllerResolver();
$request->attributes->add($matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));

$controllerArray = $resolver->getController($request);
$controller = $controllerArray [0];
$methodArgs = $resolver->getArguments($request, $controllerArray );
```

I have not touched the htaccess file (I do not have to, right?).

My routes looks like:

```
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: "MyProject\\Module\\Login\\Controller\\LoginController::indexAction" }

index_login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: "MyProject\\Module\\Login\\Controller\\LoginController::loginAction" }
```

THe url of my virtual host is "myproject.dev". If I type myproject.dev, than indexAction will be executed. But if I additional type /login, than the browser says error 404 (object not found). 
I`ve debugged and index.php will not be called by typing "myproject.dev/login"...
I guess I have to touch the htaccess?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Hmm, I think I get it. I had to write the file name in the url: `myproject.dev/**index.php**/login`
This will explain it. Now I have to look up, how to remove the index.php from the url.

Comment: `Now I have to look up, how to remove the index.php from the url` you have to use htaccess for this.